# explorer.exe eating all CPU, how to to detect culprit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-explorer, process-explorer, x86-64

Windows 7 64bit.

I am using ProcessExplorer from Sysinternals, and it says, that the offending call is

```
ntdll.dll!RtlValidateHeap+0x170
```

however, the call stack towards the entry is always different, so it's hard for me to track the problem. Maybe it's a mal-programed trojan, causing exceptions in Explorer.exe, but that is only a wild speculation.

Explorer.exe is then consuming 25% (a core on a dual core). Killing the process makes the task bar go away, respawning from task manager, and half a minute later it's again eating all CPU cycles.

Comment: I suspect a DLL that isn't releasing resources for some reason. What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: It's most likely a shell extension. You can use [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to identify all shell extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Use SysInternal's sister program, Process Monitor, to see what it's actually doing.